# Angular 2 constructor injection vs direct access

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

Q1. I have a common utility class with some utility/helper methods (no get/post request). First thing I have to ask is that whether it should be a simple class or an `@Injectable` class. Because both can be used after importing in any component class like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

Injectable()
export class Utils {
}
```

OR

```
export class Utils {
}
```

Q2. If it's injectable then I have to import this in my component class, inject in the constructor, and must have to add in providers array then I can use any method of the injected class/service like

```
import { Utils } from './../shared/utils';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'abc',
    templateUrl: './abc.component.html',
    providers: [Utils]
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _u: Utils) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._u.someMethod();
    }
}
```

But beside this I can directly access the service methods without constructor injection and without having to add in providers, which is a short way like

```
import { Utils } from './../shared/utils';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'abc',
    templateUrl: './abc.component.html'
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        Utils.someMethod();
    }
}
```

So I wanted to know which one is better and recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using it in constructor,

1. You use a separate instance of the service across your component.
2. When used as Injectable(), it should be declared inside the **providers** array of the module.

   ```
   constructor(private _u: Utils) { }
           ngOnInit(): void {
                   this._u.someMethod();
          }

    //private - _u => is specific inside this component
   ```

In case of direct access, the resources are used as it is which might create following problems

1. Memory Leaks
2. Less Reusability
3. In case of observables, until an observable is unsubscribed you cannot subscribe to it again.

Comment: So every helper class should be used by constructor injection? And how can be separate instance of service in component as services are always singleton?

Comment: Not exactly, but in major cases YES, it should be injected.

Comment: Even if there are no observables, just flat methods?

Comment: can u say few examples? What exactly your expectation.?

Comment: In simple I have a service with some helper methods only and it doesn't depend on any other service, so should it be injectable and should it be constructor injected or not?

Comment: @AliShahzad if this helped you?

Comment: Yes but still have some confusions

Comment: need more help reach me out at fb @aravind2109

Answer (score 2):

Q1. `@Injectable()` is not required if `Utils` doesn't depends on any other service, but if it does you must use the `@Injectable()` decorator :

```
   // 1 case

    @Injectable()  // <--- required
    export class Utils {
       constructor(private _otherService : OtherService){}
    }


    // 2 case
    @Injectable()  // <--- not required
    export class Utils {
      constructor(){}
    }
```

In both cases you have to add the service in the providers array of the component.

Q2. Use the first approach because it makes it easy to test your component by passing a `MockUtils` service.