# Typescript : Method can be static

Tags: typescript, static

typescript v 2.1.0

I wrote the following ServerRouter.ts

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

export class ServerRouter {
  router: Router;

  /**
   * Initialize the ServerRouter
   */
  constructor() {
    this.router = Router();
    this.init();
  }

  /**
   * GET index page
   */
  public  getIndex(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    res.render('index');
  }

  /**
   * Take each handler, and attach to one of the Express.Router's
   * endpoints.
   */
  init() {
    this.router.get('/', this.getIndex);
  }

}

// Create the ServerRouter, and export its configured Express.Router
const serverRouter = new ServerRouter().router;
export default serverRouter;
```

Webstorm inspection warning

*> Method can be static*

is raised about the getIndex() function :

BUT

If I changed it to static

> public static  getIndex()

, the I get an error :  TS2339 'getIndex' does not exist on type 'ServerRouter'

What should I change ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 44):

A static method exists on a *class* rather than an object instance. You would have to change `this.getIndex` to `ServerRouter.getIndex` in your `init` function.

WebStorm suggests making methods static if they don't touch any of the state of an instance, since it suggests that the method exists at a level that is general to *all* instances of that class.

You can find out more about `static` in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) (see the "Static Properties" section).

Comment: According to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600571/3872998) direct access has issues...so which is the best practice?? I just removed all "static" from members and fixed all occourrences with injection ahahah should I revert?

Comment: @TonySamperi I would agree with that answer and go with dependency injection on a singleton instance instead of static methods. It makes your code easier to test as well as the advantages described in that answer. Don't worry too much about TypeScript suggesting those methods can be static - a dependency-injected singleton instance is just an alternative solution to static classes, and is not inferior at all.