# Javascript code readability - split into smaller functions or not?

Tags: javascript, angular, function, typescript, ecmascript-6

Bit of a simple question but just wanted to get some advice.

I am building a simple tax calculator app with Angular, I have all the calculation working fine at the moment but when it come to the code design I do not know if I doing it the right way or not. so...

When was first laying day some code I had this to work out the superannuation amount

```
this.superAnnuationAmount = (this.incomeAmount / 100) * this.superAnnuationPercentage
```

Pretty simple. But now I have come to clean up my code I thought it would look and read more better if I do this...

```
this.superAnnuationAmount = this.getSuperannuationAmount(this.incomeAmount, this.superAnnuationPercentage);

private getSuperannuationAmount(income: number, percentage: number): number {
    return (income / 100) * percentage;
}
```

Now I know it makes hardly any difference, apart from it make it more readable I guess. I am also going to be taking this approach for the more complex functions. However in my IDE I have the linting error of `Method can be more static`.

How can it be more static? And is taking big functions and putting them into more readable smaller functions the right approach?

Comment: @Pac0 The question isn't the same, he's asking about other stuff too, but it's true that the title of this question could be better stated.

Comment: Agreed - will update the title

Comment: I removed my duplicate flag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript : Method can be static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052041/typescript-method-can-be-static)

Answer (score 3):

Since your function does not use instance variables on the object (it does not use `this`), you can make it static

```
private static getSuperannuationAmount(income: number, percentage: number): number {
    return (income / 100) * percentage;
}
```

You don't have to do it though - it's just your linter coming at you.

I think a more clean approach would be to use a getter:

```
public get superAnnuationAmount(): number {
    return (this.incomeAmount / 100) * this.superAnnuationPercentage;
}
```

Now you can just use your regular `superAnnuationAmount` and it will do the computation using instance variables.

Comment: The use of the getter looks interesting - will look into this now

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if I were the developer who has to maintain your code, I would prefer the first version, because it's clear enough, specially because of the `superAnnuationAmount` variable that [explains](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html) the intention of the mathematical expression on the right. In the second version, I wouldn't have all the information at glance, the logic is in two different places now, and the reward about readability doesn't justify that dispersion (and making the method static would make things worse, if there's only one place where the calculation needs to be performed).

Comment: I hear what your saying - thank you for your opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi it can be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052041/typescript-method-can-be-static).
A static method exists on a class rather than an object instance. Please provide class structure for more details.